# Is there a way to get the html of form fields including current values?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to get the resulting HTML of form fields where the user has entered data? For example, I only seem to be able to retrieve something like this using innerHTML:

```
<input type="text" />
<textarea></textarea>
```

But I would like to get something like this:

```
<input type="text" value="John Smith" />
<textarea>Hello! How are you today?</textarea>
```

Edit:

Here's code for a minimum reproducible example:

```js
function go() {
  alert(document.getElementById('example').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id=example>
  <input type=text />
  <textarea></textarea>
  <input type=button value=go onclick="go()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Rojo Shared it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get value from html form by using javascript. You can get value which user input in the form.

You have to declare id in input field or textarea field.

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="John Smith" />
<textarea id="name">Hello! How are you today?</textarea>
```

Now get the field by using javascript.

```
const input = document.getElementById("id")
```

Now to get value, just use ***value*** property of this element.

```
input.value
```

or you can use it directly

```
document.getElementById("id").value
```

For getting entire dump from a html form.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="BookPackageForm">
```

Then fetch the form element by using forms object.

```
var formEl = document.forms.BookPackageForm;
```

Get the data from the form by using FormData objects.

```
var formData = new FormData(formEl);
```

Get the value of the fields by the form data object.

```
var name = formData.get('name');
```

Comment: Thank you. But I was hoping to get an HTML dump of the current state of an entire form at once.

Comment: Do you mean How can get entire values from a form at once?

Comment: @user16179552 this answer is the only way to retrieve **values** from a form. Information entered in a form does not change the `innerHTML` of that element. It only changes the `value` of that [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

Comment: In the previous answer I add more info for getting entire values. See it.

Comment: @Rojo That's what I needed to know, thank you. Its interesting that I could do something like this with by using non-form elements and the contenteditable attribute, but not form elements!